# How to get inputs from multiple peers in a message-oriented microservice

Tags: architecture, microservices, domain-driven-design

Here are two basic but related questions about distributed systems.  Suppose we are lucky enough to be writing microservices that will sit at the end of a queue (Azure Service Bus, AWS SQS, or Kafka).  Most or all of the services depend on inputs (messages) from other services to do their jobs.

1. Should we strive to limit inter-service communication to the message queue?  There's always a temptation to make REST calls to other services (bypassing the bus) when you want something immediately.  But maybe this is a symptom of pre-microservice thinking.
2. If the answer is yes--we should strive for total isolation--what do we do when service **A** needs messages from both **B** and **C** in order to do its job?  **A** has just seen a message from **B** that it should act on.  Does **A** wait around for the needed **C** message to come across the bus?

Maybe **A** could put a message on the bus asking **C** to do something and **C** could reply across the bus, but this is starting to feel awfully REST-like.

Answer (score 0):

> Should we strive to limit inter-service communication to the message queue?

Not necessarily a message queue; but usually via indirect, asynchronous information transfer.

I push information to you by writing it into a information store that you can read, and I pull information from you by reading it out of an information store that you can write.  But you-the-service aren't necessarily running when I'm interacting with the information stores, and I'm not idle-blocking waiting on you to do your work.

Typically, when a service doesn't have all of the information that it needs to do some work, it will reschedule that work for later, or invoke some contingency measures to announce that it is not meeting its service level objectives for this unit of work.